# How does PHP 8's password_verify prevent rainbow table attacks when no salt is specified?

Tags: php, encryption

Consider this code a web site may use for verifying a password. Note that no salt is specified, as is recommended.

```
$givenPassword = /*whatever was entered*/;
//look up $username, $encryptedPassword
if (password_verify($givenPassword, $encryptedPassword))
{
   //log user in and do good things
}
```

Suppose a hacker has stolen the database and wants to know if "secret" is the password for $user.

```
$givenPassword = "secret";
//look up $username, $encryptedPassword
if (password_verify($givenPassword, $encryptedPassword))
{
   //report so hacker can do evil things
}
```

The code for encryption is identical. No salt is specified. If I don't specify the salt but PHP does, why doesn't the hacker have access to the same salt with his own PHP interpreter, so that the salt is useless? If the hacker *doesn't* have access to the salt created by my call to password_hash when he calls password_verify, how does my call to password_verify have access to the right one?

This question is about not about how salts work but how password_verify, not md5 or other older functions with programmer-defined salts, can share the salt with my call to password_verify without it also being available to someone else.

Comment: It adds random salt to the password. So the same password can get many different hashes, and it's not feasible to create rainbow tables with all the salts.

Comment: It doesn't prevent the second code from working. But that's not a rainbow table.

Comment: It doesn't prevent dictionary attacks. The only protection against that is not using dictionary words.

Comment: [security.se] would be a better place to ask about security mechanisms. There's nothing specific to PHP in this.

Comment: Barmar: how does my call to password_verify have access to the correct salt, but the hackers doesn't?

Comment: I've edited the question; I hope that works. This question relates to how password_hash and password_verify share information without it being available to hackers -- not about how salts work, or encryption.

Comment: The salt is concatenated to the hashed password. So it's available to hackers. But they would have to create a rainbow table with every possible salt combined with every possible password, which is impractical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`password_verify($givenPassword, $encryptedPassword)` does not prevent rainbow table attacks. Such attacks consist on having a precomputed list of `$encryptedPassword`, so once you put your hands on a leaked database you can do a simple database lookup, and you can also quickly detect all users that happen to be sharing passwords.

Rainbow table attacks are prevented by `password_hash()`, which adds a random salt before hashing, what means that you'll never get the same hash twice for the same password:

```
var_dump(password_hash('1234', PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
var_dump(password_hash('1234', PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
var_dump(password_hash('1234', PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
```

```
string(60) "$2y$10$P8ZHgvrmmyyBujjrLQnvR.3iFYcrJqklGr73bckAvx3pVqkKyPj0e"
string(60) "$2y$10$UbwElT41Jwb6goz6bojEsu.I7ifKXo2yp5lYMJPlT2y8YpofkAuSy"
string(60) "$2y$10$VK5wC760UwHIaKvpMXxz5upN1AV6SH7iALsJH0wcggX.Dsg4TeUgS"
```

(If you run this code, you'll also get different hashes than me).

This renders precomputed tables useless.

The only role that `password_verify($givenPassword, $encryptedPassword)` plays is that it's *slow*. `$givenPassword` needs to be hashed with the original algorithm and salt used (which are stored in `$encryptedPassword`), and that's done with specially crafted hashing algorithms specifically designed to be slow. This makes it unfeasible to just start verifying every string combination.

To have an idea of how slow it can be, you can change the default options:

```
$start = microtime(true);
var_dump(password_hash('1234', PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 17]));
$end = microtime(true);
printf("Time: %f seconds\n", $end - $start);
```

```
string(60) "$2y$17$17ZLamp.RFlZOjExzbCH0.auz2Lg5cPsZxDl9K.2oCtrR3Uxut0Y2"
Time: 5.655422 seconds
```

```
$start = microtime(true);
var_dump(password_verify('1234', '$2y$17$17ZLamp.RFlZOjExzbCH0.auz2Lg5cPsZxDl9K.2oCtrR3Uxut0Y2'));
$end = microtime(true);
printf("Time: %f seconds\n", $end - $start);
```

```
bool(true)
Time: 5.681215 seconds
```

Comment: I think what you're saying is this: * Each encryption $encryptedPassword of a password (say, 'secret') looks different. * If I'm a hacker and call password_verify ('secret', $encryptedPassword), it will work just fine. *The value of having the salt is to make the $encryptedPasswords look so different the hacker can't build a table; he has to try each password individually.

Comment: Being precise, it is not encryption but a hash, and it does not only _look_ different, it _is_ entirely different. But, yes, that's how it works.

Comment: I ask if you can the comments of my first comment on your answer (in whatever way you want to paraphrase it) in your answer, because I think your answer needs that clarification. But anyway, I have my answer. Tx.

Answer (score -1):

Technically the way the [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function generates a hash for a password with a random salt. In order to being able to verify the password, usually both the salt and the hash are saved in the database as you get them combined in one string already.

If a hacker would be able to get the combination of salt and hash of the password, the hacker would be also able to verify if a given password matches the hash+salt combination. Though as technically the combinations could overlap with other passwords (although pretty much only in theory for the implemented algorythms) the hacker can never fully be sure the given input is the password the user actually used or maybe just a string generating the same hash.

Though for rainbow tables, as the size of the possible combinations can quickly exceed certain limits, it is not very practical to keep those combinations for all possible passwords.

Also you could consider adding a custom salt to every input before processing, so the hacker would also need to have access to your source code for the custom salt used in addition to the random one generated by the algorythm. It doesn't slow down the hacker a lot but at least he would need to brute force 2-3 of your passwords and doesn't get the salt on the first run, if the salt isn't to obvious.

e.g.

```
$hash = password_hash($input."mysalt");

if(password_verify($input."mysalt", $hash)){
  //valid
}
```

Talking about dictionary attacks, this mechanism also is relatively safe, as there is not only one possible hash+salt combination for one string but many.

Let's say a user uses `pw123` as password. Every time the `password_hash()` function is called it will use a different salt. (Up to the size of the salt, which is quite big), so saving just the hash+salt for this one password in a rainbow lookup table would result in a huge amount of entries already.

Comment: *"usually both the salt and the hash are saved in the database"* — Yes, but this is already both contained in the return value of `password_hash`. You make it sound as if you need to save both separately somehow, which isn't the case.

Comment: *"for rainbow tables, as the size of the possible combinations can quickly exceed certain limits"* — That is what distinguishes *rainbow tables* from a plain database of all possible hashes. Rainbow tables are a tradeoff between space and computation time to _make it feasible_ to store precomputed collections with a reasonable lookup time.

Comment: *"you could consider adding a custom salt"* — That doesn't really do anything, it just alters the password you're hashing. Once an attacker has found _one_ password through brute forcing and caught on to your _pepper_ (the actual term), it's pointless.

Comment: I modified the wording to be more clear, maybe you could also edit if you feel like there needs to be more clarification?

Comment: Overall you just kind of seem to be missing the point, or you express it the wrong way around. You can't reverse a hash, you can only try every possible password to brute force a hash. With a sufficient cost parameter that becomes very slow even for a single hash. By adding a random salt, you'd need to repeat this process an enormous number of times and spend a ton of storage space to create any sort of precomputed lookup table. This in combination makes brute forcing a hash, and especially a whole database of them, practically infeasible.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to tell... however your wording is more on point.